# Problems rooting an evo shift

Tags: rooting

I'm on day 2 of the great quest for permanant root.  I have followed the guides [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=932153) and [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-permanently-root-htc-evo-shift-4g/) to the letter and still my hboot shows "S-On".  Hboot says:

```
SPEEDY XE SHIP S-ON
HBOOT-0.93.0001
RADIO-1.07.00.1129
eMMC-boot
```

Visionary will temp root, I go through all the steps, the md5's match, but when I go into hboot, it always says S-ON.  How do I get this thing rooted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to permaroot anyways?

I'd try a factory reset and then try again.

Comment: I wiped everything and tried again from the start and it took.